# How to prove this collection is a sigma-algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $G$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $T$ then $A=x^{-1}(G)$ is $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ ,  $C=\{1,2\}$ , $F=P(\Omega)$ , $F=\{\emptyset , \Omega, \{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$

How can I prove that this collection is $\sigma$-algebra, I think that I only need to give the cases of the inverse function but I think that is not enough.

If someone could help me to demonstrate it or give me an idea I would greatly appreciate it.
And sorry for my spelling I'm learning English

Comment: You have written $F=P(Ω)$ and  $F=\{\emptyset , \Omega, \{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$.  They are not the same

Comment: You need to check the $\sigma$-algebra contains $\Omega$, and is closed under complements  and under (countable) unions

Comment: So, what happen with the inverse function ??

Comment: Check out any basic outline on sets and mappings, and your should find some rules on how unions and intersections interact with inverse images. That should give you what you need.